# error while creating room in muc using xmpp

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack, tigase, muc

I am crating room using android application using smack library.

Following are the code for create group chat(room) using muc:

```
MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
muc = manager.getMultiUserChat("myroom@conference.192.168.1.4");
muc.create("myroom");
muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(DataForm.Type.submit));
```

Following are the log when perform above commands for create group in MUC:

```
<presence to='myroom@conference.192.168.1.4/myroom' id='wvAb9-11'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'></x><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw='/></presence>

<presence type="error" xmlns="jabber:client" id="wvAb9-11" from="myroom@conference.192.168.1.4/myroom" to="dk@yama/Smack"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" node="http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack" hash="sha-1" ver="NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw="/><error type="cancel" code="404"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">S2S - destination host not found</text></error></presence>

org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: remote-server-not-found - cancel
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:232)

at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:311)

at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:400)

at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:376)

<presence to='myroom@conference.192.168.1.4/myroom' id='wvAb9-11'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'></x><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw='/></presence>

<presence type="error" xmlns="jabber:client" id="wvAb9-11" from="myroom@conference.192.168.1.4/myroom" to="dk@yama/Smack"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" node="http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack" hash="sha-1" ver="NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw="/><error type="cancel" code="404"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">S2S - destination host not found</text></error></presence>

org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: remote-server-not-found - cancel

at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:232)

at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:311)

at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:400)

at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:376)

at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.create(MultiUserChat.java:354)

at com.example.sufalam.tigasechatdemo.UserListActivity$3.onClick(UserListActivity.java:72)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.create(MultiUserChat.java:354)

at com.example.sufalam.tigasechatdemo.UserListActivity$3.onClick(UserListActivity.java:72)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create the room `myroom` at the conference server `conference.192.168.1.4`, but in return you get a `remote-server-not-found` error.

The server name `conference.192.168.1.4` looks odd, as it is a mix of a hostname and an IP address.  You need to figure out what the conference server is actually called, either by checking its configuration, or (if the conference server is running as a component of the server you're connecting to) by [performing an "items" service discovery request](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#items).

I'm not familiar with Tigase, but it appears that its MUC service comes in a [separate component](http://www.tigase.net/content/tigase-muc). You may want to check that it's been installed and started properly.

Answer (score 0):

To create room please install spark in your pc and login with openfire user account and from there create room you will get

> yourroomname@coneference.storege

in my case i have get this. so now i tried to create room through my application and give server name as

> coneference.storege

and group name. my group is created successfully. please not give ip address when you create room.